# Subscribing to a tag always subscribes for 1 email per day

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, subscription

As the title says, if you go to a tag filter page ([example](https://stackexchange.com/filters/12684/the-witcher-2)) and subscribe for email updates every 15 minutes, you'll end up with a subscription for email updates once per day.

<sub>I also ran across a bug where I had to completely unsubscribe from a filter and resubscribe to it in order to change the email frequency, but I can't reproduce it.  (I could go to the tag filter page and change the frequency, but if I refreshed the page or went to my subscriptions tab it was still be set to once per day).  The tags this happened with were [portal](https://stackexchange.com/filters/9969/portal) and [plants-vs-zombies](https://stackexchange.com/filters/6063/plants-vs-zombies).</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [filter you linked to](https://stackexchange.com/filters/12684/the-witcher-2?sort=newest) is infrequently updated; questions seem to be spaced out by a couple days on average.

So, even if you subscribe to receive emails every 15 minutes, you'll end up receiving an email within 15 minutes of each question being asked, which is every couple days.

**EDIT**

Based on your comments, my initial answer doesn't seem to address your concern. Nevertheless, this seems to have been fixed in the 2 months since you asked the question, since it's not reproing now. I'll change the tag from [status-norepro] to [status-completed].

Comment: I didn't say I ended up getting emailed infrequently, that's fine.  The subscription itself was set to email once per day rather than once every 15 minutes, and happened with all tag filters.  It's obviously been fixed in the two months since I posted this, though, so great!

Comment: @Mathew Oh, ok. Looking through our change logs.. on June 14 we fixed a bug in which "every 3 hours" subscriptions were rendering as "daily". But AFAIK, we never knew about or fixed a bug with "every 15 minutes" subscriptions.

Comment: It could have been a problem with both, I didn't test every 3 hours subscriptions.  Thanks for the info though!